# To edit the listview

Tags: android, listview

I am able to Display the contents in a listview.But I want to edit that contents,Is it possible in android,If yes how to do it.I have not found anything on editing the item of the listview.The code below is to display listview

```
dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.row,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Why not using an ArrayAdapter instead ?

Comment: @Bixi : how is the comment relevant to the question, and what would be so good about an arrayadapter ?

Comment: You cannot "edit" (change) the content of a ListView using a CursorAdapter because you cannot change the content of a Cursor.

Comment: editing means to change the contents of the list items

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleCursorAdapter` is bound to a `Cursor`. So update the contents of the `Cursor` (requery for e.g.) then use `dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh the `ListView`.